# How to avoid stacking headings in documentation, theses etc

Tags: api-documentation, headlines

I very often come into situations where I either stack headings, i.e. I have headings with no content, or where I write some content under a heading just for the sake of it not being empty.

Completely made up example:

> ### 7 Descriptions of country flags
>
> #### 7.1 Description of the Finnish flag
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris fermentum, erat eget pretium gravida, tortor augue lacinia eros, quis ornare tortor dolor sed est. Mauris consequat ultrices massa at suscipit. Suspendisse interdum ac nulla vel vestibulum. Curabitur ut nisl lobortis, dapibus sem a, volutpat mauris.
>
> #### 7.2 Description of the Swedish flag
>
> Pellentesque euismod pharetra purus, sed pretium lacus posuere quis. Ut elementum nisi quis arcu sollicitudin, id fringilla quam bibendum. Morbi lacus nibh, condimentum quis odio facilisis, dignissim mattis purus. Vivamus velit odio, gravida quis eleifend molestie, pellentesque quis nunc.

In these cases, I usually put something completely pointless under 7, like "This section will describe the flags of some European countries". What would be a better solution?